# value of integral expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In proving a result, I have come across the expression $\int_{c}^{d}{g(t)}dt<\epsilon$ for converging improper integrals. given the integral $\int_{a}^{\infty}{g(t)}dt$ converges, it is known that $\left|\int_{c}^{d}{g(t)}dt\right|<\epsilon$ $\forall c,d>M>a$ where $M$ is arbitrary. My question is can I set $\int_{d}^{\infty}{g(t)}dt\le\epsilon$ since the integral is bounded above.

Thank you in advance!

(EDITED, SORRY POSTED THE WRONG LIMITS OF INTEGRATION)

Comment: The thing you said "it is known" is not typically true. You seem to maybe be mixed up about what this step is about. The point is that the integral over the "tail" is small because the integral on $[c,d]$ is already close to the entire integral on $[c,\infty)$ if $d$ is large enough.

Comment: Hello @Ian, sorry I put the wrong limits for integration, thank you for pointing that out ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

$$\int_{c}^{\infty}{g(t)}dt = \lim_{d \to \infty}\int_{c}^{d}{g(t)}dt \le \epsilon.$$

Comment: There is a little typo: the lower bound on the left should be $c$, not $d$

Comment: @ Didier: thanks

Comment: I am very sorry @Fred ; I miss typed the limits of integration. Now the question makes sense, I'd love for you to have another crack at it!